# Term for a specific hand motion?

Tags: single-word-requests

Mel Brooks makes a motion with his hand [here](https://youtube.com/watch/?v=xMSFWZpDZjo) in a scene from [Robin Hood - Men in Tights.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107977/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

[image: hand waggle]

Is there a term for that gesture?

Comment: For people who can't access the video: he's making the "kinda sorta" motion where you hold out your hand and then waggle it sideways back and forth. It's the hand motion you would make if somebody asked you how likely it was that you failed a test and your answer was "ehhh, fifty-fifty."

Comment: [so-so gesture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmhSfx8n_zk), also called "hand rocking".

Comment: By the way, *feygele* (in the video) means *homosexual* in Yiddish (it also means a few other innocuous things). This might help in understanding the motion.

Comment: Just for posterior, er, posterity you should identify the source of the video.  I presume this is some movie of his?

Comment: A little bit more, a little bit less. Oy vey, that sounds downright shaky to me.

Comment: @HotLicks [Robin Hood - Men in Tights](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107977/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

Comment: @ShaulBehr - I never would have guessed that one.

Comment: @Graffito yours is the best guess so far.  Care to post it as an answer?

Comment: The term "hand waggle" (or "waggled his hand") suggested by Kevin Workman seems as good as any,

Comment: It's body language which speaks volumes...er...so to speak.

Comment: Did it come from a mime of a scale balance or a see-saw? I'm sure I remember people doing a two-handed version with the hands cupped upwards as though comparing the weights of two bags in the old days. This meant the same thing but you needed both hands free.

Comment: Per @DavidHandelman alone, Brooks gestures as he asks "Feygele?" (= little bird, fay, fairy). Despite the *Yes&no* meaning in general, here he's using the limp wrist stereotype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's fluttering his hand, which is usually interpreted as uncertainty. Maybe yes, maybe, no, but probably no. Wavering in regard to a decision.

Flutter: to move with quick, wavering or flapping motions. Webster's New Collegiate.

Answer (score 0):

This is, as [@Graffito](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/132252/graffito) wrote in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350638/term-for-a-specific-hand-motion/610572#comment812238_350638), the "***so-so gesture***".

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gestures#:%7E:text=The%20so%2Dso%20gesture) explains,

> The so-so gesture expresses neutral ("so-so") sentiment or mild dissatisfaction ("meh"), or can describe an uncertain situation ("maybe"). The hand is held parallel to the ground (face down) and rocked slightly.